# javascript working in localhost but not when hosted?

Tags: javascript, hosting

I'm trying to implement a simple image slider on my website but it doesn't seem to want to work. Nothing happens at all. Nothing I can think of has worked thus far so I thought I'd ask here. This is my code.

```
window.onload = function(){
   image = document.getElementById("slideShow");
   index = 0;

   setInterval(slide, 3000);
};

function slide(){
    index++;
    if(index >= 6) {index = 0;}
    path = "images/Slideshow/image"+index+".jpeg";

    image.setAttribute("src",path);
}
```

Comment: What does the console say? My first guess is that the script isn't loading in time.

Comment: Console says this. "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."

Comment: Are you sure your image path is correct?  It's a relative path so it will be relative to the page URL.  If you put a `console.log("hello")` statement in your `slide()` function, does it ever get called?

Comment: I just figured it out after you suggested that, I went into the console and it said it didn't find the .js file. I had the name typed wrong in my <scrpit> tag on the page. What a dumb mistake, glad I found it though! Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You can either delete your question or answer your own question.  But, you should close it one of those two ways.

Answer (score -1):

window.onload is pretty cheesy because nobody seems to agree on what onload actually means.

i would recommend you use

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    // code
});
```

Another thing u should be aware of is slow loading. If the scripts gets loaded after the ready event has been fired then your code will never trigger.

A solution is wrapping the ready function is a seperate module.

```
var eventReady;
(function(){
    var funcArr = [];
    eventReady = function(func){
        funcArr.push(func);
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        for(var i=0;i<funcArr.length;i++){
            try{
                funcArr[i]();
            }
            catch(e){
                throw(e);
            }
            finally{
                continue;
            }
        };
        eventReady = function(func){
            func();
        }
    });
})();
```

and then use the module like:

```
eventReady(function(){
    // code
})
```

Comment: There's nothing "cheesy" about window.onload.  It always happens AFTER DOMContentLoaded so it's unclear how you're recommendation to switch could possibly solve the problem.

Comment: Yes it's the standard.But browsers implement them differently. But even if that's not the problem i provide an additional solution. You should be be easy on the downvote if the problem is actually solved. It should weigh a false statement don't u think?

Comment: I see no explanation in your answer for how it could possibly solve the OP's issue and the answer contains several wrong assertions.  That's what downvotes are for.